# PHP sort Array by 3rd field largest to smallest without a named key

Tags: php, sorting

I made an array using the instructions and now have the following:-

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Argentina 
        [1] => AR 
        [2] => 20.1 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => Austria 
        [1] => AT 
        [2] => 20.1 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => Australia 
        [1] => AU 
        [2] => 20.1 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [0] => Azerbaijan 
        [1] => AZ 
        [2] => 20.1 
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [0] => Bosnia and Herzegovina 
        [1] => BA 
        [2] => 20.1 
    ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
        [0] => Barbados 
        [1] => BB 
        [2] => 20.1 
    ) 
    [6] => Array ( 
        [0] => Bangladesh 
        [1] => BD 
        [2] => 20.1 
    ) 
    [7] => Array ( 
        [0] => Belgium 
        [1] => BE 
        [2] => 20.1 
    ) 
    [8] => Array ( 
        [0] => Burkina Faso 
        [1] => BF 
        [2] => 20.1 
    ) 
    ........so on 
)
```

I now need to be able to sort this largest to smallest based on the number value. I have checked but I can't find a way to do it when I don't have named keys?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

To get the max value:

```
$value = max($array);
```

And get the corresponding key by using:

```
$key = array_search($value, $array);
```

To get the array value in descending order -

```
usort($yourArrayName, function ($item1, $item2) {
    return $item2['value'] <=> $item1['value'];
});
```

And in ascending order -

```
usort($yourArrayName, function ($item1, $item2) {
    return $item1['value'] <=> $item2['value'];
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I’m trying to sort the array largest to smallest so that I can extract the top 5